# How do I show in a Contribution report (if I can) the other particpants payment sttaus if they were paid for by another attendee

Tags: civicontribute

My finance person wants a contribution report that doesn't just show the contributions for the initial person signing up, but lists individuals that were paid for as additional attendees signed up for and paid for as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the data you want lives in pricesets, so perhaps this extension will expose it: https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports

Comment: Thanks Alan, not seen that before, I'll get it installed and have a play